# How do I flush DNS settings in ubuntu, like we do in Windows?

Tags: networking, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I clear the DNS cache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2219/how-do-i-clear-the-dns-cache)

I am having some issues with my Internet. The ISP wants me to reset/flush the DNS settings. So my question is how do I flush the DNS settings on ubuntu like we do in windows with ipconfig/flushdns.

Any help, would be highly appreciated.