# How to flush dns in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: dns

how to flush dns of  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64)

have tried many things form [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2219/how-do-i-clear-the-dns-cache) and [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-ubuntu-flush-clear-dns-cache/) also but nothing is working

Comment: why do you think it is not working? Any stat with `dig`, Any error message?

Comment: @braiam  if u have noticed that i have mentioned the same question that the solution dint worked out for me.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Install nscd using the following command if not yet

```
sudo apt-get install nscd
```

Flush DNS Cache in Ubuntu by restarting the nscd

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

Comment: there is no inbuild tools?

Comment: no @jdog, it's not - but this one is - http://askubuntu.com/questions/2219/how-do-i-clear-the-dns-cache

Comment: this did not work for me (but installation and restart commands did work fine). However, when I do ssh root@serverA, it still brings me to the old server...

Answer (score 66):

According to this SU answer *"[How to clear DNS cache in Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/a/163296/286168)"*, Ubuntu by default does not provide DNS cache service. But if you have one that you installed manually, you could usually restart those services to clean the cache. Here are some examples <sup>[(source)](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/flush-dns-cache-ubuntu-13-04-12-10/)</sup>:

---

- Run this command to flush DNS:

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart
  ```
- Followup the above command with this:

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/networking force-reload
  ```

---

- To flush `nscd` DNS cache:

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
  ```

---

- To flush `dnsmasq` DNS cache:

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
  ```

---

- If you use BIND this should flush DNS:

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/named restart
  ```

  or

  ```
  sudo rndc restart
  ```

  or

  ```
  sudo rndc exec
  ```

  BIND (>= v9.3.0) supports flushing records from a particular domain and also the lan and wan views.<sup>[source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-ubuntu-flush-clear-dns-cache/)</sup> Examples:

  > ```
  >    sudo rndc flush
  >
  >    sudo rndc flushname askubuntu.com
  >
  >    sudo rndc flush lan
  >
  >    sudo rndc flush wan
  > ```

---

Comment: This answer is spot on. As a followup, if you have not installed a DNS caching service/local DNS server, then the best course of action is probably to restart your router. Most routers have a DNS cache built-in and turned on by default that DHCP sets up.

Comment: Thank you, both, I was going to comment above on the incomplete answers... However, this one had covered it; cool! :)