# How to (re)configure my internet connection? (DNS resolving failed)

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, proxy, dns

A couple of days ago I was working with `ipython notebook` and it opens me a page in my web browser (Google Chrome) and I was able to work with the notebook (zero problems with my internet).

Then, I configure my network connection with a public proxy in order to get access to a blocked webpage, after that I erase the proxy configuration.

Now, when I open the `ipython notebook` I get the next error:

> **ERROR: Not Found**
>
> While trying to retrieve the URL http://some.localhost:8888/tree:
>
> **DNS resolving failed**
>
> Your cache administrator is webmaster.

Moreover, I have been having internet connection problems, for instance, I have to reload several times a webpage in order to open it, most of the times I get a `No internet error` despite I am connected.

So, the question is: How I get rid of this DNS error?

*Additional comments*: I am in Ubuntu 12.04. I am having this problem in my workplace as in my home, therefore I believe it has to do with my network configuration and not with my router.

I don't know which should be my default configuration since I don't know too much about networks, but I have the following configuration in `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search some.workplace.page
```

The file `gedit /etc/network/interfaces` have:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface  
auto eth0
```

I tried to flush the DNS as explain in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414826/how-to-flush-dns-in-ubuntu-12-04) but that didn't work.

`ifconfig eth0` gives:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:42:49:58:36:xx  
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
Interrupt:18
```

Comment: Try this command in your Terminal:
`sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @Naveen: I got `bash: /etc/resolv.conf: Permission denied` even though I can edit `/etc/resolv.conf` with sudo

Answer (score 1):

Your current `/etc/resolv.conf` expects a local (stub) resolver, so check that the resolver is actually running: `sudo netstat -unlp | grep :53` should report at least one line of the form

```
udp        0      0  127.0.0.1:53    0.0.0.0:*       776/named
```

If not, you may need to restart the `bind9` service (`sudo service bind9 restart`) or to change the `nameserver` line in `/etc/resolv.conf` to point at a known-good resolver: either your router (probably `10.0.0.1` or `10.1.1.1` or `192.168.0.1`), or one supplied by your ISP, or a public one such as Google's `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: I believe this partially works! I am not getting the DNS error and I can surf through the internet with the browser, but now, programs like spotify or dropbox can't connect. do you know what  could be the problem now?