# Why the programs don't connect to internet except for the browser?

Tags: networking, internet, dropbox, spotify

I [solved](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521579/how-to-reconfigure-my-internet-connection-dns-resolving-failed) a problem of getting a "DNS resolving failed" in my computer, now I can surf through internet with the browser without problems but programs, such as: dropbox, spotify, mendeley desktop doesn't connect to internet. **Do you know what could be the problem?**

Moreover, when I try to restart the network with

> sudo /etc/init.d/networking force-reload

doesn't finish to process the command.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I solve my problem as follow: I edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` by modifying the line **host**, I add: `hosts:          files dns wins mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4`