# How to flush DNS in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: dns, hosting

We recently moved our website to a new server. But after changing the NS (name server) records, I can't access my website. The hosting provider said we need to flush the DNS settings in order to see the new website.

I searched relating to this but I couldn't find a way to flush DNS settings in Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Usually NS takes time to update its records & it depends. As far as I know, Ubuntu doesn't cache DNS by default but your ISP (assuming). Refer [**How do I clear the DNS cache?**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2219/how-do-i-clear-the-dns-cache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install nscd using the following command if not yet

```
sudo apt-get install nscd
```

Flush DNS Cache in Ubuntu by restarting the nscd

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm new to Ubuntu and this forum too! Thank you telling me that :D

Comment: @user245632 you are welcomed

Comment: @Pramod an upvote is fair

Comment: @Ask That application only enables DNS caches, as mentioned by AzkerM and me, Ubuntu does not cache DNS by default.

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual need to flush DNS as Ubuntu doesn't cache DNS. Instead, your ISP may be caching DNS. If you want to enable DNS cache, install `pdnsd` and `resolvconf`.

Comment: @Pramod if it has helped you, please upvote! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

## Ubuntu 18.04

Ubuntu 17.04 and onwards use systemd for DNS.

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

Comment: All very well, but it is a long way from 13 to 18.