# Location of curl dns cache file and location of ubuntu global cache dns file

Tags: dns, curl

I have curl installed on my ubuntu instance. Can any one let me know location of curl dns cache file as well the location of global cache dns file.

I was going through the curl documentation and could not find any.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2219/how-do-i-clear-the-dns-cache

Comment: If you have a specific goal in mind, perhaps you could open a new question that outlines that specific goal.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does not cache dns information. Neither does curl itself. In my experience, curl along with ssh and other network-related programs on Linux run a fresh dns query every time they run.

I have seen the same to be true on CentOS/RHEL/Fedora which I also use frequently.