# How can I flush the DNS on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: dns, 17.04, systemd, resolv.conf

How can I flush the DNS on Ubuntu 17.04?

I seem to have a few DNS issues at the moment since upgrading to 17.04 from 16.10 and went to flush the DNS but I can't find how to.

Can anyone tell me please?

Comment: I ran into the same thing yesterday. This took care of my issue: https://superuser.com/a/1200745

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clear the DNS cache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2219/how-do-i-clear-the-dns-cache)

Comment: I have removed the solution part from the question. But you can find it [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/906476/2). Please post the solution part in the "Your Answer" field below. It's completely okay to answer your own question and accept your answer. Also please [don't add "SOLVED" tag to title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question).

Comment: I've found nothing works short of rebooting the system and walking on egg-shells

Comment: If you are using Chrome and are having cache issues, it'll also help to clear Chrome's dns cache chrome://net-internals/#hsts

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You may use this command: `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches`

To verify that flush was sucessfull, use:
`sudo systemd-resolve --statistics`

Sample output:

```
Cache
  Current Cache Size: 0
          Cache Hits: 101
        Cache Misses: 256
```

Comment: This answer improves on the previous one so I have marked it as the one true answer.

Comment: When I run `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches`, I get `systemd-resolve: unrecognized option '--flush-caches'`.

Comment: Same as @NathanFriend - Checking the --help output, this subcommand was removed in 17.10

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and the subcommand is there.

Comment: @NathanFriend same thing for 16.04

Comment: Not there in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 34):

This command should restart the local name service and flush the local DNS cache:

```
systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

There is probably a way of getting it to just flush the cache instead of restart, but restart suited my purposes.

Comment: This seems like the only way to clear everything to 0 when running `--statistics` immediately after. On Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 0):

I made this:
https://github.com/dunderrrrrr/dnscache

Maybe thats what youre looking for.

**Installation**

```
$ git clone git@github.com:dunderrrrrr/dnscache.git
$ cd dnscache/
$ sudo cp dnscache /usr/local/bin/
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dnscache
```

**Usage**

There are two arguments that can be passed to the script, clear or stats. Both of them should be self explanatory.

```
$ sudo dnscache clear
DNS cache has been cleared!
[...]
Cache
  Current Cache Size: 0
[...]
```

Comment: Could you please expand the answer and maybe add installation process and usage?

Comment: It's all on github.

Comment: I agree, but link-only answers are not considered as answers  on [Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Thanks a lot for expanding your answer.

Comment: It's only running  `systemd-resolve --flush-caches` then `systemd-resolve --statistics`.  : https://github.com/dunderrrrrr/dnscache/blob/master/dnscache

Comment: Well, thats the point. It's much faster typing `sudo dnscache clear`. Time is money, right.

Comment: seems like a cheap attempt to farm rep.