# How to clear DNS cache in 18.04

Tags: networking, dns

Please don't flag this question as a duplicate because I really need your help. I once used OpenDNS in my router to block some websites & now I'm stuck with at whatever I do. I have already removed OpenDNS from my router & tried half of the commands suggested in other question but none of them work for me. Most of the websites which deal with a proxy, adult content etc. are all blocked & I'm requesting for a solution.

Comment: Try this for proxy https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle

Comment: `Please don't flag this question as a duplicate` - It _is_ a duplicate.  The correct answers are https://askubuntu.com/a/909173/446317 and https://askubuntu.com/a/907558/446317 https://askubuntu.com/a/929478/446317 - that's 3 correct answers in two other questions.  Duplicate.

Answer (score 14):

This should clear it

```
# sudo systemd-resolve --flush-cache
```

You can check with

```
# sudo systemd-resolve --statistics
```

- it should show 0 in Current cache size

  ```
  DNSSEC supported by current servers: no
  Transactions
  Current Transactions: 0
  Total Transactions: 93750

  Cache
    Current Cache Size: 0
    Cache Hits: 18686
  Cache Misses: 28576

  DNSSEC Verdicts
        Secure: 0
      Insecure: 0
         Bogus: 0
  Indeterminate: 0
  ```

Comment: My current cache is still not 0

Comment: You need to get into the **ROUTER** settings and flush the cache there as that's where your DNS lookups entries are cached, not on your local computer. If you need help with that, you might want to visit a forum that focuses on your router model.

Comment: @Michael what version of Linux are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this version also has two (2) DNS caches, like Ubuntu 20.10.

Please check the full tutorial to flush DNS caches:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1315569/136919