# Which service is responsible for my networking? How to flush DNS Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS?

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns

I have changed my DNS settings a few weeks back. It solved the problem and i forgot about it, but now I cant remember what changes I've done, because I've copied a few commands from askubuntu and it worked...

Now I want to flush my DNS but when I do as [How can I flush the DNS on Ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906476/how-can-i-flush-the-dns-on-ubuntu-17-04) I recieve this message:

> sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
>
> Failed to flush caches: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.

1. What are the popular Ubuntu 18.04 networking providers?
2. How do I flush my DNS and how to know its TTL or TTL of a record in it from command line?

Running: `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`

```
sudo apt-get install whois
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main network management daemon in Ubuntu is [NetworkManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager).

The error you're seeing might be caused by missing symlink inside `/etc/systemd/system`.

Please try to recreate it by using:

```
sudo ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service
```

If you're having issues with systemd-resolved.service you can try to restart it. It should also flush DNS caches as a result.

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

To see the domain TTL's you can use `dig` from `dns-utils`

```
apt install dnsutils
dig askubuntu.com
```

sample output:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
askubuntu.com.      247 IN  A   151.101.1.69
askubuntu.com.      247 IN  A   151.101.65.69
askubuntu.com.      247 IN  A   151.101.129.69
askubuntu.com.      247 IN  A   151.101.193.69
```

247 is the current TTL